# Users That Have the APK With Version Code 3 May Need to Accept the android.permission.INTERNET permission

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

When I upload the new version of the app on play console get this warning:

> Users that have the APK with version code 3 may need to accept the android.permission.INTERNET permission, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app.

What does this mean?

Comment: supposed you added a new feature to your app new version(with version code 3) and you declare in the manifest android.permission.INTERNET permission and now when you are updating your app the play store somehow warns you that your new feature may make users not to download the new version of your app.

If it's right verdict you should not care about that so much, as the users will download the new version if they want to use new features - I think it's inevitably for users to download at some moment the new version

Answer (score 0):

That's mean that Auto app update won't work with this build.

Users have to go to Google Play and update the App manually.

This is done because you have added new permission to this new version.